# notify users with django signals _ Django

Tags: python, django

suppose we have a model **MarkPost**. this model has ForeinKey relation to **Post** model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    TITLE = (
             ('1', 'USA'),
             ('2', 'Europe'), )
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TITLE)

class MarkPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                             related_name="marked")
```

example:

```
foo_post = Post.objects.create(title="1")
marked_post1 = MarkPost.objects.create(user="Foo", post=foo_post)
```

I'm trying to write some signal notification that if another Post instance made with value **marked_post1.post.title** ,notify the related user in **marked_post1**.I made a signal function for this purpose.

signals.py

```
def created_post(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    marked = MarkPost.objects.get(pk=1)
    marked_title = marked.post.title
    if created and instance.title == marked_title :
        #logic of my code
        print(" new post made ")

post_save.connect(created_post, sender=Post)
```

this will work for one instance but how can do this in a general way for every user that marks a Post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a defined logic behind the `MarkPost`'s id calculation,

```
def logic_to_find_markpost_id(req_data):
    # do stuff to find MarkPost's id
    return markpost_id


def created_post(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    markpost_id = logic_to_find_markpost_id(req_data)
    marked = MarkPost.objects.get(pk=markpost_id)
    marked_title = marked.post.title
    if created and instance.title == marked_title:
        # logic of your code
        print(" new post made ")


post_save.connect(created_post, sender=Post)
```